# SSD - split Virtual Machines and Data or both on same SSD?

Tags: ssd

Is there any benefit in keeping Virtual Machines and Data on two different SSDs?  Just thinking about the wear from the writes to the Virtual Machines being much higher than for the Data partition.  Does it make sense to seperate these two or it that just making extra complication for no reason.

Comment: **Does it make sense to separate these two or is that just making extra complication for no reason.** No, it doesn't make sense. Yes, it is extra complexity for no good reason.

Comment: If you are getting enough wear from writes that you're going to need to replace one of your SSDs you're still going to have to go through the pain of replacing one of your SSDs. If you split it just means you won't need to replace the other one at the same time.